# Can we always construct an element not on a list?

Tags: set-theory

After thinking about Cantor's diagonal argument for the uncountability of $\mathbb{R}$ and a similar argument that a set and its powerset have different cardinalities, I am wondering if it's possible to construct a set $S$ and a list of elements from $S$ such that, although we know there is some element of $S$ not on the list, we can't actually find an explicit construction of it?

Edit: if there's an answer that doesn't require advanced knowledge that would be appreciated.

Comment: "Finding an explicit construction" is a vague statement. What exactly do you want to be impossible about this element?

Comment: [Related](http://mathoverflow.net/q/47458/6085).

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want $S$ such that $\exists x: \forall y: [y\in S \implies y\ne x]$.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean "explicit construction"?

Answer (score 2):

You can start with L and Levy collapse $\omega_2$ to $\omega_1$. In the extension, let S be the (countable) set of constructible reals and note that no non constructible real is ordinal definable since Levy collapse is homogeneous.

Comment: You probably meant the collapse of $\omega_1$ to $\omega$. Otherwise you don't add any new real numbers, and so the set of constructible reals is the same set of real numbers of the extensions which is certainly uncountable.

Comment: You are right. I wanted $\omega_2$ to become $\omega_1$ using finite conditions: $Fn(\omega, \omega_1)$.